# Which is the esper level of Kiyama Harumi when she uses Multi-Skill?

Tags: a-certain-scientific-railgun

So Multi-Skill is an ability adquired by Kiyama Harumi when connecting to the Level Upper Network, where she is able to use multiple abilities of those who used Level Upper.

Which is the esper level of Kiyama Harumi when she uses it?